# ending loop without use of break and convert for loop to while

Tags: java

this is my code

```
import java.util.*;
public class test3
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int mark;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int student = 1; student <=10; student++)
        {
            System.out.println("enter mark");
            mark = sc.nextInt();
            if (mark > 0)
            {
                sum = sum + mark;
            }
            else
            {
                student = 10;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("sum is" + sum);

    }
}
```

i want to change this code so that the loop ends without having to use student = 10 to end loop. i cant think of anything that would end the loop. and also convert it to a while loop so far i have

```
int student = 1 ;
int sum = 0;
int mark
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (student <= 10)
    {
        System.out.println("enter mark");
        mark = sc.nextInt();
        sum = sum  + mark;
        student++;
    }
```

but i dont know how to end loop if 0 is input we're not allowed to use break; to exit loop could i get some help please?

Comment: While student <= 10 and not [condition you want to break on, i.e., mark <= 0]

Comment: You want to end the `while` loop and you can't use `break` or `if(student == 10)`? Is this a homework? If yes then your teacher is well, let's say weird. Add extra condition to loop, and if input is 0 set some variable to false.

Answer (score 1):

The ways for ending loops are:

- using `break`
- if the condition is not satisfied in the next interation
- Including the loop in a method and using `return`

Answer (score 0):

Use `while (student <= 10)` condition and `student = 10` statement to exit the loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    int mark;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int student = 1;
    while (student <= 10) {
        System.out.println("enter mark");
        mark = sc.nextInt();
        if (mark > 0) {
            sum = sum + mark;
        } else {
            student = 10;
        }
        student++;
    }
    System.out.println("sum is" + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
int student = 1 ;
int sum = 0;
int mark
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while (student <= 10) {
    System.out.println("enter mark: ");
    mark = sc.nextInt();
    if (mark > 0) {
        sum += mark;
    } else {
        student = 10;
    }
    student++;
}
System.out.println("sum is = " + sum);
```